# metaprogramming map on data.table list-columns

Tags: r, data.table, metaprogramming

I cannot map over a nested column using data.table.
I made it an example.

```
library(data.table)    
library(purrr)

DT <- setDT(list(
  gp = c("A", "B"),
  data = list(
    setDT(list(d1 = c(1, 2, 3), d2 = c(2, 2, 4), d3 = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.4))),
    setDT(list(d1 = c(10, 20, 30), d2 = c(20, 20, 40), d3 = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.4)))
  ),
  metric = c("max", "min")
))
```

`choose_a` and `choose_b` are two of the n columns nested.
`calc_name` is the name of the calculated new column, that has been opereted by
the `calc_metric_mean` function

```
calc_metric_mean <- function(a, b, metric){
  if(metric == "max"){ 
    return(mean(c(max(a), max(b))))
  }
  if(metric == "min"){
    return(mean(c(min(a), min(b))))
  }
  if(metric == "q74"){
    return(mean(c(quantile(a, 74), quantile(b, 74))))
  }
}

choose_a <- c("d1", "d2", "d2")
choose_b <- c("d3", "d1", "d2")
calc_name <- paste(choose_a, choose_b, sep = '')
metric <- "max"

for(i in 1:length(calc_name)){
  DT[, calc_name[[i]] := map_dbl(
    .x = data,
    ~calc_metric_mean(
      a = choose_a[[i]],
      b = choose_b[[i]],
      metric = "max"
    )
  )]
}
```

The result would be

```
   gp              data d1d3 d2d1 d2d2
1:  A <data.table[3x3]>  1.7  3.5    4
2:  B <data.table[3x3]> 15.2 35.0   40
```

**ADDED 2021-03-18**
Second quiz: How about if you have the parameter "metric" in a column, outside the nested data?
The result would be

```
   gp              data metric d1d3 d2d1 d2d2
1:  A <data.table[3x3]>  max   1.7  3.5    4
2:  B <data.table[3x3]>  min   5.1   15   20
```

Comment: I suggest to simplify your code a little bit, using formula as metaprogramming interface is confusing, especially when there is `dcast` usage as well. It doesn't cost much to simplify your code to make it more clear.

Comment: @jangorecki I've added a a tiny and better example. 
I cannot managed this approach: https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-list-columns-in-data-table/20491.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Variation: using variables from the nested objetive**

`lapply` is enough. See the @diaggy's Answer.

**Second Variation: using variables from and Outside the nested objetive**

If you have to load a parameter from other column, it is neccesary pass from `lapply`, to `mapply`.

```
for(i in 1:length(calc_name)){
  set(DT, NULL, j = calc_name[i],
      value = mapply(function(x, m){
        calc_metric_mean(a = x[[choose_a[i]]], b = x[[choose_b[i]]], metric = m)
      }, x = DT$data, m = DT$metric, SIMPLIFY = FALSE
    )
  )
}

> DT
   gp              data metric d1d3 d2d1 d2d2
1:  A <data.table[3x3]>    max  1.7  3.5    4
2:  B <data.table[3x3]>    min  5.1   15   20
```

`SIMPLIFY = FALSE` is required if it will return a list instead a vector.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, if I haven't understood the question correctly, but if you're trying to produce the desired output using `DT`, using a `for()` loop with `set()` is an option:

```
for(i in 1:length(calc_name)){
  set(DT, NULL, j = calc_name[i],
    value = lapply(DT$data, function(x){
      calc_metric_mean(a = x[[choose_a[i]]], b = x[[choose_b[i]]], metric = "max")
      }
    )
  )
}

DT
```

This approach is in someways a nested for-loop, which isn't the most elegant, but it gets the job done and looping with `set()` can still be quite fast since it's updating by reference. One note is that this approach takes advantage of the fact that a `data.table` is a list with `x[[choose_a[i]]`.

To get my code to work, I had to make two small changes to your example set up. First, because you created `DT` with structure, you need `setDT(DT)` to use `set()`. Second, I edited `calc_metric_mean()` to be more explicit about what it returns. Otherwise, it returned `NULL` for me:

```
calc_metric_mean <- function(a, b, metric){
  if(metric == "max"){ 
    return(mean(c(max(a), max(b))))
    }
  if(metric == "min"){
    return(mean(c(min(a), min(b))))
    }
  if(metric == "q74"){
    return(mean(c(quantile(a, 74), quantile(b, 74))))
  }
}
```

Comment: I've  added a second variation. Could you help me with this @diaggy?

Answer (score 1):

There's another answer thanks to wonderful @diaggy 's answer.

```
for(i in 1:length(calc_name)){
  DT[, calc_name[i] := lapply(DT$data, function(x){
    calc_metric_mean(a = x[[choose_a[i]]], b = x[[choose_b[i]]], metric = "max")
  })][]
}
```

This leads to the desired result too.

```
> DT
   gp              data d1d3 d2d1 d2d2
1:  A <data.table[3x3]>  1.7  3.5    4
2:  B <data.table[3x3]> 15.2   35   40
```

There're some comments to do:

1. The final empty `[]` is neccesary to list off the `:=` result in the data.table (see 2.23 in [faqs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html)).
2. The double call `x[[` is neccesary to assess the inner columns in a list-column. For some reason, x[, choose_a[i]] returns the character choose_a[i] and this won't work.

In the comparison, it is better @diaggy 's solution:

```
              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
 eval(diaggys_set) 3.589102 3.849702 4.487934 4.054001 4.516901 10.4261   100
      eval(direct) 4.749001 5.127901 5.844534 5.386051 5.985651 12.9724   100
```